# How to get an array result set from Laravel where condition

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, where-in

I am trying to get a result set from a laravel eloquent query whereby I match a column against a list of values in an array.

```
$authenticated_operation_ids = AccessControl::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
    ->where('entity_type_id', '=', $operation_entity_id)
    ->pluck('entity_access_id')->toArray();
$authenticated_operations = Operation::whereIn('id', $authenticated_operation_ids);

return view('page.index')->withOperations($authenticated_operations);
```

Comment: You're forgetting `->get()` at the end of your queries.

Comment: In mongodb native ids are created as _id property. You should change id to _id if you didn't make it so deliberately.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it as:

```
$authenticated_operation_ids = AccessControl::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('entity_type_id', '=', $operation_entity_id)->pluck('entity_access_id')->toArray();
$authenticated_operations = Operation::whereIn('id', $authenticated_operation_ids)->get();
return view('page.index')->withOperations($authenticated_operations);
```

Add `get()` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

1) `pluck` returns a single value from a single row. You want `lists` to get a single column from multiple rows. `toArray` may not be needed, as it returns an array of values

```
$authenticated_operation_ids = AccessControl::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
    ->where('entity_type_id', '=', $operation_entity_id)
    ->lists('entity_access_id');
```

2) You're forgetting to actually retrieve the rows in your second line:

```
$authenticated_operations = Operation::whereIn('id', $authenticated_operation_ids)
    ->get();
```

Comment: In Laravel 5.2 the `lists` method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query builder objects has been renamed to `pluck`. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

Comment: Ah ha, thanks! That renders #1 moot, then. At least, if they are using 5.2. No version was mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call get() function on the result set to obtain results. The modified code will be like

```
$authenticated_operation_ids = AccessControl::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('entity_type_id', '=', $operation_entity_id)->get()->pluck('entity_access_id');
$authenticated_operations = Operation::whereIn('id', $authenticated_operation_ids)->get();
return view('page.index')->withOperations($authenticated_operations);
```

or you can use a cursor to process it.